# Dismiss multiple controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

How can I go back to several controllers back?
The picture is an example

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna back to root view controller you can use:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Another way if you want to come back not to root view controller.

In your current view controller:

```
guard let navigationController = self.navigationController else {return}
        for controller in navigationController.viewControllers {
            if let neededVC = controller as? SomeViewController {
                navigationController.popToViewController(neededVC, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both viewcontrollers are in the same navigation stack you can use the navigationcontroller's function `popToViewController(_:animated:)`.

```
navigationController?.popToViewController(theViewControllerInstanceYouWantToGetBackTo, animated: true)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621871-poptoviewcontroller.

In your specific case you can also use `popToRootViewController(animated:)` since - according to your screenshot - you want to pop back to the navigationcontroller's initial viewcontroller.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use segue then use '[Unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)'

for this write given code in your 'A view controller'

```
@IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {



}
```

In B_viewcontroller, On press button call 'Unwind segue'. with `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueForA_VeiwController", sender: nil)`

With the help of Unwind segue you can send data also